# object values spread into each other

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have `const a = { _: { a: 1 }, __: { b: 2 }, ___: { c: 3 } }`

How can I merge the object values of this object like so:

I want Result: `{ a:1, b: 2, c: 3}`

Comment: please add what you have and what you want. the first one is not valid.

Comment: Your object is not valid, you can have repeitive keys, so you will endup getting only last value in this case

Comment: Just for your information, the value of `a` will be different from what’s on the right side of the assignment. More to the point, you can spread many times, like `{ ...object1, ...object2 }`, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign the spreaded values.

```js
const
    a = { _: { a: 1 }, __: { b: 2 }, ___: { c: 3 } },
    result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(a));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values` and `reduce`

```js
const a = { _: { a: 1 }, __: { b: 2 }, ___: { c: 3 } }

let op = Object.values(a).reduce((op,inp) => ({...op,...inp}) ,{})

console.log(op)
```

**On side note:-** Keep in mind `...` will make a shallow copy only if you more nested object you need to deep clone them